Non-existent PCI device present in lspci
I've just updated my uncommon laptop (xiaomi notebook pro x) by replacing pre-installed ax201 wi-fi card with a be200 sibling. The thing is, lspci still sees ax201:
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 (rev 20)

I can find some information saved by journald:
# journalctl  --since '30m ago' | grep 00:14

kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: [8086:a0ed] type 00 class 0x0c0330 conventional PCI endpoint
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: BAR 0 [mem 0x82480000-0x8248ffff 64bit]
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.2: [8086:a0ef] type 00 class 0x050000 conventional PCI endpoint
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.2: BAR 0 [mem 0x6103188000-0x610318bfff 64bit]
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.2: BAR 2 [mem 0x6103191000-0x6103191fff 64bit]
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.3: [8086:a0f0] type 00 class 0x028000 PCIe Root Complex Integrated Endpoint
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.3: BAR 0 [mem 0x6103184000-0x6103187fff 64bit]
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.0: Adding to iommu group 7
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.2: Adding to iommu group 7
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.3: Adding to iommu group 8
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 3
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: hcc params 0x20007fc1 hci version 0x120 quirks 0x0000000200009810
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: xHCI Host Controller
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: new USB bus registered, assigned bus number 4
kernel: xhci_hcd 0000:00:14.0: Host supports USB 3.1 Enhanced SuperSpeed
kernel: usb usb3: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
kernel: usb usb4: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
mtp-probe[401]: checking bus 3, device 2: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-5"
mtp-probe[402]: checking bus 3, device 3: "/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb3/3-7"
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CSR_RESET = 0x11
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x0
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x3f190430
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x3f190430
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x3f190430
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x3f190430
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x3f190430
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x3f190430
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x3f190030
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x1
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0x04006ec2
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x0 vector 0x6
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0xb8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 1]: 0xb8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 2]: 0xa8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 3]: 0xa8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 4]: 0xa8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 5]: 0xa8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 6]: 0xa8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 7]: 0xb8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 8]: 0xe8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 9]: 0xe8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 10]: 0xe8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 11]: 0xe8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 12]: 0xe8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 13]: 0xf8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 14]: 0xf8047c60
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Host monitor block 0x22 vector 0x0
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3:     value [iter 0]: 0x89cec019
kernel: iwlwifi: probe of 0000:00:14.3 failed with error -110

and I'm running one of the latest kernels:
6.8.4-1-MANJARO #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Thu Apr  4 20:38:32 UTC 2024 x86_64 GNU/Linux

It looks very similar to this problem with this solution, but the platform mentioned there is Windows, not Linux.
How is this possible? I'm quite sure there was only a single device before. There's no second ax201 soldered on the motherboard, yet it's still in there and doesn't look responsive (iwlwifi doesn't pick it up, while it is supported by the kernel for quite a while). Is there an option to "completely" remove it? Finally, can it affect the Bluetooth capabilities of newly installed be200 (currently my machine doesn't have any discoverable bluetooth adapter)?
Output for the be200 (I assume that difference in addresses may be important):
kernel: pci 0000:66:00.0: [8086:272b] type 00 class 0x028000 PCIe Endpoint
kernel: pci 0000:66:00.0: BAR 0 [mem 0x82300000-0x82303fff 64bit]
kernel: pci 0000:66:00.0: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
kernel: pci 0000:66:00.0: 7.876 Gb/s available PCIe bandwidth, limited by 8.0 GT/s PCIe x1 link at 0000:00:1c.0 (capable of 15.753 Gb/s with 16.0 GT/s PCIe x1 link)
kernel: pci 0000:66:00.0: Adding to iommu group 16
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x2001910, cnv-id 0x2001910 wfpm id 0x80000000
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: PCI dev 272b/00f4, rev=0x472, rfid=0x112200
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.4.125
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: loaded firmware version 86.fb5c9aeb.0 gl-c0-fm-c0-86.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: Detected Intel(R) TBD Bz device, REV=0x472
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: loaded PNVM version 8443a58d
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: Detected RF FM, rfid=0x112200
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: base HW address: a0:02:a5:e0:88:14
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0 wlp102s0f0: renamed from wlan0
NetworkManager[550]: <info>  [1712335056.4552] rfkill0: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:66:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill0) (driver iwlwifi)
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
kernel: iwlwifi 0000:66:00.0: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
ModemManager[586]: <msg> [base-manager] couldn't check support for device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:66:00.0': not supported by any plugin


Admittedly I'm speculating a bit here, as I'm not really familiar with how devices work at that level.
However, notice the initialization line
kernel: pci 0000:00:14.3: [8086:a0f0] type 00 class 0x028000 PCIe Root Complex Integrated Endpoint

and
kernel: pci 0000:66:00.0: [8086:272b] type 00 class 0x028000 PCIe Endpoint

Again I know very little about this but it seems clear that they're initialized as two different kind of devices.
Digging deeper (copied straight from here):

The root complex in PCI Express (PCIe) is the intermediary between the
system’s central processing unit (CPU), memory, and the PCIe switch
fabric that includes one or more PCIe or PCI devices. It uses the link
training and status state machine (LTSSM) to manage connected PCIe
devices. The LTSSM detects, polls, configures, recovers, resets, and
disables the devices as required during operation.

So my understanding is that the PCIe root complex of your device, whose purpose is explained above, is named after the card is meant to hold (speculating even more: possibly because it has been custom designed for that specific card - *please don't quote me on this*). But it's, in fact, a completely separate device that has nothing to do with the WiFi card itself.

i have no way of verifying it (at least as for now), so i can't accept it, but this looks like a very very plausible explanation

@Etki I just now realized that I have a similar secondary setup (Ubuntu running on a NUC 12, hence still a mobile Intel platform, which has a removable m2 wifi card), I'll cross-check with what my journald says - shrug - maybe there's a chance I may see something similar going on with my setup

i think i've found a solution, and the problem was specifically in my laptop - given how special it is, i don't expect this to be present on intel devices, which should have quite higher quality standards

The reality turned out to be rather hilarious. It seems that some kind of state persisted between reboots and even bios resets - and i am blaming hardware, though i don't have 100% confidence (it may be uefi as well, i think). When i've installed ax201 back, neither installed system nor live usb couldn't see the card that was installed there in the first place, which was quite unexpected. However, the classic move, pulling the battery out of the laptop, did the trick - everything returned back to normal, and the laptop now seem to properly interact with a new wi-fi card (though right now it's ax210, not be200), both wi-fi and previously missing bluetooth are present, and lspci shows no traces of ax201 (which were there when a new card was installed, but battery hasn't been yet pulled out).

Go figure... But if I had to guess I'd still guess something UEFI-related somehow, what else could persist across reboots / system reset? :| I'm glad you figured it out though!
